# Android: waiting for response from server just for a minute otherwise showing alert dialog

Tags: android, response, android-alertdialog

I need to show a dialog box if the internet network is low and  response from server side is taking time more than 1 minute. how to accomplish this task.
I am using following code for it.
BUt it is not working intentionally.:

```
try
{
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(hc.getParams(),60000);
 int timeoutSocket = 60*1000;
  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(hc.getParams(), timeoutSocket);
}


 catch(ConnectTimeoutException e){
                                    //System.out.println(e);
                                    m_Progress.cancel();
                                    alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminEbooks.this).create();
                                    //alertDialog.setTitle("Reset...");
                                   // System.out.println("internet not available");
                                    alertDialog.setMessage("Low internet connectivity?");
                                    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                           alertDialog.cancel();
                                       }
                                    });
                                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I'm doing this :

```
    public void UseHttpConnection(String url, String charset, String query) {
    try {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Charset", charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = connection.getOutputStream();
            output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showError2("Check your network settings!");

        } finally {
            if (output != null)
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        int status = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
        Log.d("", "Status : " + status);

        for (Entry<String, List<String>> header : connection
                .getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
            Log.d("Headers",
                    "Headers : " + header.getKey() + "="
                            + header.getValue());
        }

        InputStream response = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[30 * 1024];
        while ((bytesRead = response.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            byte[] buffer2 = new byte[bytesRead];
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, buffer2, 0, bytesRead);
            handleDataFromSync(buffer2);
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        showError2("Check your network and server settings!");


    } catch (IOException e) {
        showError2("Check your network settings!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Basically if your connection is time out it will throw you an `IOException` which you need to catch and create the alert dialog there. At least this is what I'm doing and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to put it in a background thread. I recommend using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

You'll need to override `onPreExecute()`, `doInBackground()`, and `onPostExecute()` at the very minimum to accomplish what you are trying to do.

`onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` are executed on the UI thread so your dialogs can be shown in these methods.

I recommend `doInBackground()` to return a `boolean` so `onPostExecute()` can display the correct dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Make a method for checking the response time,

```
public boolean checkURL() {

    boolean exist = false;
    try {
        URL url=new URL("http://.................");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        urlConnection.connect();

        exist = true;
    } catch(Exception  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
         exist = false;
    }

    return exist;
}
```

it return flase if not responded in 60 secs

Now perform the condition,

```
if(chcekURL){
} else {

                                    alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminEbooks.this).create();
                                    //alertDialog.setTitle("Reset...");
                                   // System.out.println("internet not available");
                                    alertDialog.setMessage("Low internet connectivity?");
                                    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                           alertDialog.cancel();
                                       }
                                    });
}
```

Comment: i checked this but it is also not working.. it just shows a black screen nothing else:(

Comment: hey neetesh its working but can u plz tell me of other way??because when my w/s progress dailog runs then i get two log from w/s. 1) for my login responce and 2) form  URL url=new URL("http://................."); so my w/s check Url two times and displaying log two times.

Answer (score 0):

For my dialogs i just use

```
String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Dialog Title");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
```